# Duplicate Target Manager

Tags: script, questions, closing, duplicates

### Description

This is a userscript that lets you mark questions as commonly used duplicate targets, and replaces the default question search in the close dialog with one that searches through your marked duplicate targets.

A new button is added below the "favorite" button:

[image]

Once a question has been added to your collection, you can associate keywords with that question. These keywords are intended to make the question easier to find.

From that point on, you'll be able to find the marked question in the close dialog:
[image]

Lastly, the script also adds a new tab to your profile page where you can manage your collection of duplicate targets:
[image]

### Installation

- **[Click to install](https://github.com/Aran-Fey/SE-duplicate-manager/raw/master/SE_duplicate_manager.user.js)**
- view [source](https://github.com/Aran-Fey/SE-duplicate-manager/blob/master/SE_duplicate_manager.user.js)

### Bug reports and feature requests

Please post bug reports and feature requests on [my GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Aran-Fey/SE-duplicate-manager/issues).

Comment: wow! excellent userscript! if there already are some collections it would be nice with some links to them.

Comment: @PetterFriberg FWIW, [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/xrrCrY90)'s my personal collection of python duplicates so far.

Comment: Great work!  May I suggest you move the source code off gist and into a repo, so that you can use the issues and pull request features of github. Using StackApps as an issue tracker will not be very fun.

Comment: @wim I'm sure there won't be enough issues to warrant moving the project to a repo... Just kidding. Repo created and post updated.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The script should now work in GreaseMonkey. If any GreaseMonkey users still have problems, please report them [here](https://github.com/Aran-Fey/SE-duplicate-manager/issues/1). Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you get a tooltip at the top of your Chrome browser saying "Apps, extensions, and user scripts cannot be added from this website" after clicking the install link, you can simply go to `chrome://extensions` and drag and drop the `.js` file that is linked to above.

Comment: is there a way to go back to SO's native search in the close dialog? for example, right now my list has one entry, and the close dialog show only that single one, can't search site-wide anymore

Comment: Is it just me or is this script no longer working? I'm getting no new icon and instead an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at refresh_in_collection_status` in the console.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure which posts you should setup with this script? I made a quick SEDE query to help you find common duplicate target posts for your tag of choice.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/909952/1132398/most-common-duplicate-targets-for-a-tag

`TopItems` it the max items you want back. Probably good to leave this less than 50.
`TargetTag` is the display name of the tag you want duplicate target posts to contain. For example, `c#` (rather than the URL encoded version).

The results are the most common duplicate targets for that tag, ordered by how often they are linked, descending order.